# Using ruby gems online

Tags: ruby, email, rubygems, smtp

I am creating a Ruby file which allows the user to send me an email directly through my website. I have been using the gem `tlsmail` and when I try my file in local everything works perfectly, I receive the emails and all the information are where they are supposed to be (like Subject, message, and so on).

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
require "cgi"
require "tlsmail"

cgi_request = CGI::new("html5")

contact_name = cgi_request["contact_name"]
contact_email = cgi_request["contact_email"]
contact_subject = cgi_request["subject"]
contact_message = cgi_request["contact_message"]
puts contact_name
puts contact_email
puts contact_subject
puts contact_message

msgstr = <<END_OF_MESSAGE
From: Mattia Bombelli <mattiabombelli.noreply@gmail.com>
To: A Private User <another-email@gmail.com>
Subject: Testing email

Just testing the file
END_OF_MESSAGE


Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
Net::SMTP.start("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "gmail.com", "mattiabombelli.noreply@gmail.com", "password", :plain) do |smtp|
  smtp.send_message msgstr, "mattiabombelli.noreply@gmail.com", "another-email@gmail.com"

end

puts "Email sent!"
```

(The only change that I made is in the shebang, in local I am using `#!/usr/local/bin/ruby`)

The problems begin when I try to put this file online into my web hosting. If I load this file into the file manager of my website, it doesn't load the `tlsmail` gem and all the outputs from the html form that I am getting disappear and nothing else happens. Permissions are right and the file is in the right folder, because if I get rid of `require "tlsmail"` I can see the output of all the html inputs that I am taking from another page of my website.

If I try to use instead `net/smtp` I don't get any email (also the final line of my code, `puts "Email sent!"` does not appear on the page, so I guess something goes wrong when I start using `Net::SMTP`. I tried following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19144476/9267899) but I have the same problem of `tlsmail` with `mailfactory`. I also tried another completely different way, with `mail` gem, but nothing happens.

What I don't understand is what I am doing wrong in requiring the gems for my file. How can I load online a gem and use it?

Answer (score 0):

Gems are loaded from host's filesystem, and if a gem is missing then `require`-ing its files will produce `LoadError` that should be visible in the logs.

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177634/list-of-installed-gems) provides a way to list gems available on server, if you don't have shell access. Perhaps you should talk to administrator of your hosting if they can run `gem install` for you.